# Selenium opening geckdriver error: NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
import time
import pyautogui
import sys
from selenium import webdriver

tabTimer = 0


fileRun = __file__
fileRun = fileRun.replace("app.py", "geckodriver.exe")

print(fileRun)




stall  = input("enter filepath: ")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(fileRun)
driver.get("htpps://google.com")
```

Whenever I try to open geckodriver, either with the method used below or just inputing the filepath as a r"" manually, it doesn't work for whatever reason and generates the error below. Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you!

```
c:\Users\ellio\Desktop\main\app.py:22: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(fileRun)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ellio\Desktop\main\app.py", line 22, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(fileRun)
  File "C:\Users\ellio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 160, in __init__   
    firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile(firefox_profile)
  File "C:\Users\ellio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 74, in __init__
    shutil.copytree(self.profile_dir, newprof,
  File "C:\Users\ellio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 555, in copytree
    with os.scandir(src) as itr:
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'c:\\Users\\ellio\\Desktop\\main\\geckodriver.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

`NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267]` means that the Firefox method of webriver is looking for a directory, not a file path. If you go down the stack trace you see that the error is thrown by `os.scandir`. `os.scandir` only accepts directories and no direct file paths.

If you ommit `geckodriver.exe` at the end of you path it should all be fine.